# Evaluate the triple sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}\sum_{k=i}^{j} 1$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I have trouble evaluating this triple sum , so far I tried this :
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}\sum_{k=i}^{j} 1 = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}(\sum_{k=i}^{j} 1) $$
$$ = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}(j-i+1)$$
$$ = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}j \space - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n-1} i \space + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}1$$
$$ = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}j) \space - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\sum_{j=i}^{n-1} i) \space + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}1)$$
$$ = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\frac{(n-i)(n+i-1)}{2})-\space \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}((n-i)i)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i)$$
$$ =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n^2-i^2-n+i)-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}ni+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^2+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}n-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i $$
$$ =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}n^2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}n+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}ni+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^2+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}n-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i $$
$$ =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}n^2+(1-\frac{1}{2})\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^2+(1-\frac{1}{2})\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}n+(\frac{1}{2}-n-1)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i $$
$$ =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}n^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}n-(\frac{2n+1}{2})\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i $$
$$ =\frac{n^3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}+\frac{n^2}{2}-(\frac{2n+1}{2})\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n(n^2+3n^2+2)}{6}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}=\binom{n-1+3}{3} $$
But *Mathematica* yields $\frac{1}{6}n(2+3n+n^2)$. My question is where is my mistake ?
$$Edit:$$
I corrected the initial mistake but I still fail to obtain the correct solution.
$$ Second Edit:$$
I corrected the second mistake and finally obtained the correct solution.

Comment: The first line should have $j-i+1$ instead of $j+i-1$

Comment: Your sum is $$\sum_{0\le i\le k\le j\le n-1}1=\binom{n-1+3}{3}$$ similar to as done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512143/how-to-evaluate-sum-i-sum-j-sum-k-sum-l-2-where-1-le-i-le)

Comment: @Noodle I have edited my answer to take into account your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mistake right up in your first line. You've written

$$ \sum_{k=i}^{j} 1=j+i-1 $$

but this should be

$$ \sum_{k=i}^{j} 1=j-i+1 $$

**Edit: second mistake**

Between your final two lines you have written that

$$ \sum^{n-1}_{i=0} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

which should be

$$ \sum^{n-1}_{i=0} i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} .$$

This correction should lead to the correct answer.